# What is the javascript/React equivalent code for this curl code - Capital.com API (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl

I have a curl code I took from the capital.com website regarding their API but they do not have docs for node.js and I have no clue what curl code is so I do not understand it, Can anyone tell me the js equivalent assuming I am using axios to make the request.

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://api-capital.backend-capital.com/api/v1/session' \
-H 'X-CAP-API-KEY: evSl********S26P' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
 "encryptedPassword": "false", 
 "identifier": "test@gmail.com",
 "password": "Xxxx9999_"
}'
```

I tried this below but gave me a error Status 400

```
const loginHandler = () => {
    axios.post("https://api-capital.backend-capital.com/api/v1/session", {
      'X-CAP-API-KEY': "tL0xi4wvz5X8uHaD",
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'data-raw': {
        'encryptedPassword': false,
        "identifier": "hadwe",
        'password': '88asc'
      }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your Axios call makes no sense, do you even know what the curl is actually doing? If not, have you tried _finding out_? You certainly can't convert if you know neither the source nor destination tools.

Comment: No idea honestly i am a beginner at this , can you explain what it is doing?

Comment: So do some research and **find out**.

Comment: This question is specific, answerable in a couple sentences, includes an attempt at a solution. I don't see anything wrong with it. Good question.

Comment: Thanks @CollinD , I think the answer Zac gave answers the question above, I am gonna give it a try now!

Comment: @CollinD https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119/is-how-do-i-convert-code-from-this-language-to-this-language-too-broad https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/how-should-we-tag-code-translation-questions

Comment: The accepted answer to that Meta post doesn't apply to this question, because the asker posted their translation attempt and their error message. Despite the title's phrasing, it wasn't just a "translate this for me" question. No need to be snarky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--data-raw` is the body.

```js
const response = await axios.post(
  'https://api-capital.backend-capital.com/api/v1/session',
  {
    'encryptedPassword': 'false',
    'identifier': 'test@gmail.com',
    'password': 'Xxxx9999_'
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'X-CAP-API-KEY': 'evSl********S26P',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Zac's answer above is perfect, the body data which is curl is the `--raw-data` is the 2nd parameter of the `axios.post` function, and the configuration for the request is the 3rd, in this configuration you can set the headers.

I recommend using Typescript when trying to figure out these libraries, because with Intellisense or even just TS language server you get a tone of help, basically telling you what each method's interface is right on your editor.